# Libgdx libraries are missing from gradle cache after I reinstalled my system (IntelliJ)

Tags: libgdx, gradle

I reinstalled my OS (Linux Mint) today and copied all my projects over to a flash drive. After I was done setting everything up I copied 'em back over again and started to fix the problems (caused by new jdk location, new android sdk, etc).

When I opened one of my libgdx game projects I found some errors (29) similar to the following:

```
Library gdx-1.6.1 has broken classes path:
  /home/gameplayjdk/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.badlogicgames.gdx/gdx/1.6.1/bb5fe9832bcfe4bbc1de6bd357085b8a2a845d9c/gdx-1.6.1.jar [Fix]
```

Apparently the libgdx libraries are no longer present in the gradle cache, which makes sense since it's a whole new system.

Now I don't know how to make stuff work again. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

From the Terminal, run: `gradlew --refresh-dependencies`

Also, in the Gradle tool window, you can refresh all Gradle projects, though [you should only need to do this if you make changes to your Gradle scripts](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/synchronizing-changes-in-gradle-project-and-intellij-idea-project.html):

[image: Refresh all Gradle projects]